# How to select quantity by location in a row rather than column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a custom SQL view in which we can find the quantities of items by location. At the moment it provides the information perfectly in columns, however can I provide this information with a subquery or aliasing to have that information in a row?

I've tried a select subquery, however it returns

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
SELECT SKU, DESCRIPTION, QUANTITY, LOCATION
FROM INVENTORY
```

Output:

```
RB  RED BALL    0   OVERSTOCK
RB  RED BALL    1   ROOM 1
RB  RED BALL    3   ROOM 2
RB  RED BALL    5   ROOM 3
```

I would love to see:

```
SKU     DESCRIPTION    QTYOVERSTOCK QTYROOM1 QTYROOM2 QTYROOM3
--------------------------------------------------------------
RB      RED BALL            0           1       3        5
```

Comment: Search SQL Server PIVOT,  or use   `SELECT ... MAX(CASE END) AS QTYROOM1...  GROUP BY SKU, DESCRIPTION` "pivotting".. This question is a duplicate [SQL server pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SQL+server+pivot) for sure

Comment: Looks like you need a PIVOT query.

Answer (score 2):

You just need a basic pivot query:

```
SELECT
    SKU,
    DESCRIPTION,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LOCATION = 'OVERSTOCK' THEN QUANTITY END) AS QTYOVERSTOCK,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LOCATION = 'ROOM 1' THEN QUANTITY END) AS QTYROOM1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LOCATION = 'ROOM 2' THEN QUANTITY END) AS QTYROOM2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LOCATION = 'ROOM 3' THEN QUANTITY END) AS QTYROOM3
FROM INVENTORY
GROUP BY
    SKU,
    DESCRIPTION;
```

Comment: This is great Tim! Works like a charm, however when I try to add another perimeter I'm getting an invalid in select list because it's not contained in aggregate function or the group by clause....Do you know a way around this one?

Comment: If you want to add another column to the select clause, then also add it to the group by clause.